# How to convert UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList> to AudioBuffer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-audio, audiounit

I have an `AURenderCallbackStruct` setted up with an Audio Unit. In the callbacks i am getting the audio data as `ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>` . check the code below.

```
func renderCallback(inRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, ioActionFlag: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>, inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>, inBufferNumber: UInt32, inNumberFrames: UInt32, ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus {

    // How can i get AudioBuffer from iodate here ?

    return noErr
}
```

How can i get `AudioBuffer` from `ioDate` here ? Please suggest...

N.B.  I am using swift 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `memory` property of any `UnsafeMutablePointer<>` to access it's raw memory. SO your code should look something like this.

```
var audioBufferListPtr = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(ioData).unsafeMutablePointer.memory
for i in 0 ..< Int(inBufferNumber) {
    var buffer: AudioBuffer = audioBufferListPtr.mBuffers
}
```

N.B.  Swift is a quickly evolving language. So this code may change in future.